# Why won't getChildHtml Load on product view page?

Tags: blocks, template, module

I'm trying to load a custom block module tempate file onto the product_view page but it won't render itself.

Here is what I have tried:

I've declared my layout update inside my module config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <module>
                <class>Company_Module_Block</class>
            </module>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <module>
                <class>Company_Module_Helper</class>
            </module>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </module>
            <module_mysql4>
                <class>Company_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <posts>
                        <table>module_posts</table>
                    </posts>
                    <postsmeta>
                        <table>module_postmeta</table>
                    </postsmeta>
                </entities>
            </module_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_Module</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </module_setup>
            <module_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </module_write>
            <module_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </module_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <module>
                    <file>file.xml</file>
                </module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then I have my layout file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product.info">
                <block type="module/classname" name="custom_name" template="company/module/file.phtml"/>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

My block class

```
class Company_Module_Block_Classname extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    public function getText()
    {
        "Hello World"
    }

}
```

The my company/module/file.phtml

```
<?php $this->getText() ?>
```

When I try to load in my product view page I get an empty value??
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_name') ?>`

Can someone show me what I have missed please??

**EDIT**

This works in the product view.phtml file but is this the correct way??

```
<?php   echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/classname')->setTemplate('module/file.phtml')->toHtml();
 ?>
```

Comment: please show config.xml code .. your module

Comment: @AmitBera see update...

Comment: replace  <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('custom_name') ?> with
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_name') ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed my module.xml file, removed reference to my module.xml from config.xml and placed below code inside my theme local.xml now I can call

```
View.phtml

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_name') ?> 



local.xml 

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <layout version="1.0">
            <catalog_product_view>
                <reference name="content">
                    <reference name="product.info">
                        <block type="module/classname" name="custom_name" template="company/module/file.phtml"/>
                    </reference>
                </reference>
            </catalog_product_view>
        </layout>
```

Place **`OUTSIDE`** the **Default** handler